# JQuery Form plugin persistent data between functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, jquery-plugins

I have a form with multiple upload boxes that upload files with different file names, each one is triggered by its associated submit button - this all works fine - and the upload of the files works fine.

Each upload has its associated button and progressbar.

```
    <input type='file' name='file1' class='imagefile-logo' />
    <input type='submit' class='imagefile-logo upload-wrapper-btn' />
    <div class='imagefile-logo progresswrap'>...</div>

    <input type='file' name='file2' class='imagefile-design' />
    <input type='submit' class='imagefile-design upload-wrapper-btn' />
    <div class='imagefile-design progresswrap'>...</div>
    ...
```

Using jquery form plugin, once you upload two files at the same time - it updates only one box/progressbar.

I'm saving the class name to variables outside the functions, the class of the first one is being overwritten by subsequent uploads while another upload is still in progress and so it updates using the last saved class name, as you would expect.

So I need to either pass data in and be able to see this data as part of the data received by 'success' and 'uploadProgress', some kind of instance for each request or some way to index/reference them in the variables (which requires data to be available regarding who sent this upload progress call).

```
    var options = { 
            beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,    // pre-submit callback 
            success:       afterSuccess,  // post-submit callback 
            uploadProgress: OnProgress,     //upload progress callback 
            url: '/',
            type: "POST",
    };
...
    var filename;
...
    $(document).on('click','.upload-wrapper-btn', function(){
        filename = $(this)[0].className.match(/filename-[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/);
        $('#custom').ajaxSubmit(options);
    }
...
    function beforeSubmit(formData, formObject, formOptions){...}
    function afterSuccess(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){...}
    function OnProgress(event, position, total, percentComplete){
        $('.' + filename + '.progressbar').width(percentComplete + '%')
    }
```

Thanks